# Email Template Issue

Tags: html, vb.net, html-email

I have a Windows Application from where I am sending the email using Email template images. But on the different SMTP server it shows different result. It attaches the template images as an attachment.

I am using [this method](http://ramanisandeep.wordpress.com/tag/send-email/) to send the email template

Any ideas on how to send a formatted mail to all server with Identical format?

Comment: You are not giving enough information - what are the different SMTP servers? Can you show us a bit of your code that isn't performing as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the different results are just because you are using different email clients to look at the sent email? If so there are a number of 3rd parties that sell softwar and/or services to help manage that problem. Check [this out](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/testing/) for an exmaple (just one of the many I found by Googling):

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your email so that images point to an embedded image and not attached.

[Read more here](http://www.mikepope.com/blog/DisplayBlog.aspx?permalink=1264&count=no) about how to do this.  The key is to use [AlternateViews](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.alternateview.aspx) (MSDN article).

Eventually, you will need to cycle through each image in the email and embed the image while changing the src to point to a Content ID.